# How do i get the Description property in Get-ADComputer's default set?

Tags: powershell

How do i get the Description property in Get-ADComputer's default set?
I need to make this persistent across sessions (by writing it to $profile would be great).

What i get:

```
# get-adcomputer PC

DistinguishedName : CN=PC,OU=Computers,DC=myDC,DC=local
DNSHostName       : PC.local
Enabled           : True
Name              : PC
ObjectClass       : computer
ObjectGUID        : xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx
SamAccountName    : PC$
SID               : S-x-x-xx-xxxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxx
UserPrincipalName :


# get-adcomputer PC -Property Description

Description       : Some box out there, lost in the corporate shenanigans
DistinguishedName : CN=PC,OU=Computers,DC=myDC,DC=local
DNSHostName       : PC.local
Enabled           : True
Name              : PC
ObjectClass       : computer
ObjectGUID        : xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx
SamAccountName    : PC$
SID               : S-x-x-xx-xxxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxx
UserPrincipalName :
```

What i want:

```
# get-adcomputer PC

Description       : Some box out there, lost in the corporate shenanigans
DistinguishedName : CN=PC,OU=Computers,DC=myDC,DC=local
DNSHostName       : PC.local
Enabled           : True
Name              : PC
ObjectClass       : computer
ObjectGUID        : xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx
SamAccountName    : PC$
SID               : S-x-x-xx-xxxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxx
UserPrincipalName :
```

I'm using Powershell 4.0 on Windows 8.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use $PSDefaultParameterValues

Add this to your profile:

```
$PSDefaultParameterValues['Get-ADComputer:Properties'] = 'Description'
```

Note that this doesn't actually change the default values, it will just cause 'Description' to be the default value of the -Properties parameter.

If you override that by specifying -Properties and don't include Description, it won't be there.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation available here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/12031.active-directory-powershell-ad-module-properties.aspx#Get-ADComputer), Description is part of the extended properties. To quote the relevant paragraph:

> Many Active Directory Get-AD* cmdlets also support extended
>   properties. These are only retrieved if they are specified in the
>   -Properties parameter of the cmdlet. Many extended properties can also be assigned values using the corresponding Set-AD* cmdlet. Again, the
>   names of these properties may or may not match the LDAPDisplayName of
>   the corresponding Active Directory attribute.

So, I think the only way to get what you want is to define your own alias.